# StackOverflowError when removing ArrayList object

Tags: java, arraylist, loops, stack-overflow

I have an arraylist of classes and when I perform the below function I get a StackOverflowError thrown sometimes and I'm not 100% sure why, surely the if statement should rule this out? It only contains <500 elements as well and no other threads fiddle with "toCheck".

```
if(toCheck.contains(currentConsideration)){
    toCheck.remove(currentConsideration);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the equals methods of currentConsideration object?

Comment: THis piece of code looks ok. But I suspect it is used in loop. Can you give us more code?

Comment: try to remove `toCheck.contains(currentConsideration)` and use just `toCheck.remove(currentConsideration);`. It will delete the element if present.

Comment: The "contains" check is unrelated to stack overflows. Stack overflows are often caused by infinite recursion, which is probably happening elsewhere in your code. Can you post a larger code snippet containing the problem?

Comment: @PauKiatWee Good call! @OP: what is the type of currentConsideration? Please post its `equals` method.

Comment: Paul I didn't override any equals methods :)

bigGuy Unfortunately it's not used in a loop

Alex The error is being thrown on the remove line opposed to the contains line so I don't think it's that.

Andres So you think it's recursive and this just happens to be the place where it gives up?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of you are trying to remove a object which you are trying to find it in the list...
ConcurrentModificationException.

If you try to debug. At what time you will get tis error

post the solution if you find any